# Square principle and continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

I know that the Jensen $\diamondsuit$-principle implies tha continuum hypothesis, but the $\square_{\omega_1}$ implies the continuum hypothesis? Searching about these principles I found the $\clubsuit$, for who we have $\operatorname{CON}(\clubsuit +\neg\text{CH})\Leftrightarrow\operatorname{CON}(\clubsuit +\text{CH})$ and $\text{CH}+\clubsuit\Leftrightarrow \diamondsuit$, so I wanna know the relationship between $\diamondsuit$, $\square$ and CH.

Comment: Asaf has indicated that the symbols you have used in this post (the square, club, and diamondy-thing) are all standard symbols used to represent some kind of combinatorial principles.  On my first reading of your question, as an outsider to the theory you are describing, I had assumed that Unicode had made a hash of your question.  As an outsider, it would be very helpful if you could add a sentence or two to explain these symbols (I am not asking for formal definitions, just some road signs to indicate that you really meant to write what you wrote).

Comment: $\square_{\omega_1}$ is independent of $\mathsf{CH}$.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Andrés wrote, failing $\square$ requires large cardinals strength, whereas having CH or its failure requires none.